# Is this a pass by reference/value misunderstanding that's having this method fail output as intended?

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a solution to this problem (4hr50m in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBt53YbR9Kk) vid):

- Write a function `all_construct_tabular(target, word_array)` to return a 2D array containing all of the ways in which the target string can be constructed by concatenating elements of the word_array.
- Each element of the 2D array should represent one combination that constructs target.
- Elements of word_array can be reused.

Here's my test:

```
    it "returns a 2d array with x4 sub array elements" do
      result = all_construct_tabular('abcdef', ['ab', 'abc', 'cd', 'def', 'abcd', 'ef', 'c'])
      expect(result).to eq([['ab', 'cd', 'ef'], ['ab', 'c', 'def'], ['abc', 'def'], ['abcd', 'ef']])
    end
```

Here's my method:

```
def all_construct_tabular(target, word_array)
  table = Array.new(target.length + 1).each.map { Array.new }
  table[0] = [[]]

  table.each_with_index do |e, i|
    word_array.each do |word|
      if target.slice(i, word.length) == word
          new_combos = table[i].map { |a| a << word }
          table[i + word.length].push(new_combos)      
      end
    end
  end
  return table[target.length]
end
```

And here's the failing output:

```
expected: [["ab", "cd", "ef"], ["ab", "c", "def"], ["abc", "def"], ["abcd", "ef"]]
            got: [[[["ab", "abc", "abcd"], "def"], [[["ab", "abc", "abcd"], "cd", "c"], "def"]], [[["ab", "abc", "abcd"], "ef"], [[["ab", "abc", "abcd"], "cd", "c"], "ef"]]]
```

I think that I may have a situation where line 8 is actually updating the `table[i]` value, when I'm intending to just store the updated values in the `new_combos` variable. And I clearly have an array nesting problem. I've been playing with this for so long that I can't see the wood for the trees any longer and would really appreciate any guidance on where I'm going and what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

– A working, but messy solution that I arrived at (*Courtesy of many `object_id` and other `puts` statements*):

```
def all_construct_tabular(target, word_array)
  table = Array.new(target.length + 1) { [] }
  table[0] = [[]]

  table.each_with_index do |e, i|
    word_array.each do |word|
      if target.slice(i, word.length) == word
        
        new_combos = table[i].each(&:dup)
        new_combos.map(&:flatten!)
        new_combos_with_word = new_combos.map(&:dup)
        new_combos_with_word.each {|e| e.push(word) }
        table[i + word.length] << new_combos_with_word
      end
    end
  end
  return table[target.length].flatten(1)
end
```

Comment: PSA: The final `return` in any method is implied.

Comment: `Array.new(target.length + 1).each.map { Array.new }` is a clunky way of expressing `Array.new(target.length + 1) { [ ] }` where you can pass in a default block. In the first bit of code you create a whole new array, then immediately throw it in the trash, replacing it with a completely different one. Then, for some reason, you rework the 0th element to be a nested array? Far from self-explanatory here.

Comment: I'm not sure I can make much sense of that method. I can imagine a potential solution that involves trying all possible [permutations](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/array#method-i-permutation) of words, assembling the string, testing if it works, and discarding any failed attempts. Not efficient, but effective. One thing to note is Ruby often works better when it's kept *flatter*, as in if you can define your operation as a series of steps that chain together it's often easier to follow than a series of increasingly nested steps.

Comment: And I realise that final return is implied. I like to state it explicitly though as it just helps me read the code at this amateur stage in my code writing. But I'll try to start to stop doing it for the sakes of good Ruby style.

Comment: The implicit return is something you'll want to get used to because it's used a lot, and sometimes you'll return something inadvertently if you're not aware. When structured well, and this is something you'll develop an eye for over time, there isn't a whole lot of clutter in good Ruby code. The purpose of it is laid bare.

Comment: @tadman I could attempt a written explanation of the strategy here, but this video linked to at the top of my question will most likely be quicker and clearer for you to understand than a written explanation from me. His explanation of the algo strategy is about 5mins worth i think. No worries at all though if you've not the time, or inclination, for it. (Helpful comments thus far much appreciated.)

Comment: I get the gist of the issue, and I'd encourage you to explore what `permutation` can do to help solve it. As a brute-force approach it might be a good start.

Comment: Ah nice, #permutation, sorry missed link above. Wasn't aware of that Array method, will check that out . Thanks

Comment: "...or perhaps a pass by reference/value misunderstanding that's having this method fail?" You could add some `puts` function calls to check this quite easily.

Comment: [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has additional tips for debugging your code. These techniques are always good to review during your coding journey.

Comment: I'm not sure what level of ["dynamic programming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) you need here as that's a term in the Computer Science world I don't see a lot of in the more pragmatic world of actual coding, if anything I'd call that "programming", but then again it is a term from the 1950s that, like "object oriented programming" has basically been absorbed as a given in many languages.

Comment: If you're ever wondering about value vs. copy of something, check `object_id` on the elements in question. Each object has a distinct value here, even numbers, like `1.object_id` or `[].object_id`, etc.

Comment: @jbk "I could attempt a written explanation of the strategy here, but this video linked to at the top of my question will most likely be quicker and clearer" The purpose of YOU writing an explanation is to help us see YOUR understanding so that we can help you fill in any gaps or misunderstanding. The video gives the original content so we can gain our own understanding from it. We need both of these in order to help you. By leaving one of them out, you are making it more difficult for us to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
def all_construct_tabular(target, word_array)
  table = Array.new(target.length + 1).each.map { [] }
  table[0] = [[]]
  table.each_with_index do |_, i|
    word_array.each do |word|
      if target.slice(i, word.length) == word
        # `<<` modifies the original, but new combinations don't belong to that array
        new_combos = table[i].map { |a| a + [word] }
        # they belong where these combinations would end
        table[i + word.length].concat(new_combos) # or .push(*new_combos)
      end
    end
  end
  table[target.length]
end
```

Not sure if there is anything else I can do here, maybe massage some things around:

```rb
def all_construct_tabular(target, word_array)
  combinations = [[[]]]

  target.length.times.to_a.product(word_array) do |i, word|
    starting, ending = i, i + word.length
    next unless target[starting...ending] == word

    combinations[ending] ||= []
    combinations[ending].concat(combinations[starting].map { |ary| ary + [word] })
    # [["abc", "def"]]          [["abcd"]]                               ["ef"]
  end

  combinations.last
end

actual = all_construct_tabular("abcdef", ["c", "ab", "abc", "def", "cd", "abcd", "ef"]).sort
expected = [["ab", "cd", "ef"], ["ab", "c", "def"], ["abc", "def"], ["abcd", "ef"]].sort
p actual, expected
puts "Testing: #{actual == expected}"
```

```bash
[["ab", "c", "def"], ["ab", "cd", "ef"], ["abc", "def"], ["abcd", "ef"]]
[["ab", "c", "def"], ["ab", "cd", "ef"], ["abc", "def"], ["abcd", "ef"]]
Testing: true
```

Comment: Excellent @Alex, thank you. Clearly identifies that one of the key problems was that my `map` statement was updating the original value, and I don't think my `new_combo`s was holding new objects rather just references to the original array cell values. Your use of `+ [word]` solves this issue and `concat`ing the result gives the desired output. Seemingly small changes and understandings have this strategy passing perfectly!

Very helpful also to see the completely different approach in your 2nd illustrated method. `product`s new to me and interesting to see easy reading `next unless`. Thanks

Comment: I arrived at a kind of solution after learning about`#dup`, but it's messy by comparison and still has some array nesting problems that I need to solve:

Comment: My working but messy solution with `#dup` and `#flatten`ing is pasted into the bottom of my original question.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else, the knowledge that I essentially needed in order to correct my code and answer this question is well illustrated in [this](https://launchschool.medium.com/ruby-objects-mutating-and-non-mutating-methods-78023d849a5f) article, the 2nd of a three part series of articles all of which would help anyone getting to grips with Ruby's object mutation and reference / value passing behaviours.